# Split/spread a DF column where differing values of for each observation

Tags: r

Suppose I have a data frame like the following:

```
mydf <- structure(list(club_member = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L), map_of_blah = c(NA, 
                                                                                 "{Upgrade=1.0}", "{Apples=0.32786885245901637, In-Game Boost=0.06557377049180328, WalkoffGm=0.08196721311475409, Improve=0.5245901639344263}", 
                                                                                 NA, 
                                                                                 "{MystBox=0.9977827050997783, Upgrade=0.0022172949002217295, Apples = 1}", 
                                                                                 NA)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")

glimpse(mydf)
Observations: 6
Variables: 2
$ club_member <int> 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0
$ map_of_blah <chr> NA, "{Upgrade=1.0}", "{Apples=0.32786885245901637, In-Game Boost=0.06557377049180328, WalkoffGm=0.08196721311475409, Improve=0.5245901639344263}", NA, "{MystBox=0.9977827050997783, …


mydf
  club_member                                                                                                                map_of_blah
1           0                                                                                                                       <NA>
2           0                                                                                                              {Upgrade=1.0}
3           1 {Apples=0.32786885245901637, In-Game Boost=0.06557377049180328, WalkoffGm=0.08196721311475409, Improve=0.5245901639344263}
4           0                                                                                                                       <NA>
5           0                                                    {MystBox=0.9977827050997783, Upgrade=0.0022172949002217295, Apples = 1}
6           0                                                                                                                       <NA>
```

I pulled data straight from our db into r and one of the data types (Presto db) is a array map which r. In r it looks like this has been read in as a character vector for each observation.

Each vector for field 'map_of_blah' contains differing values however in total there are perhaps 15 to 20 values such as 'Apples', 'In-Game Boost', 'Improve' etc within the dataset.

I would like to process this field into a new set fields, one for each distinct value contained within the vectors under 'map_of_blah'.

Before diving into loops and regex I wondered if ayone had come across this problem before and if there's a 'right' way to do this? I keep looking at tidyr for spread() function but I'm not sure that would apply here given differing number of fields within each vector for each observation.

How can I process mydf to have additional fields for the name value pairs within map_of_blah and their corresponding values?

Comment: What do you want to do when there are multiple values for the same club member? For example, club_member 0 has both Upgrade = 1.0 and Upgrade  = 0.0022172949002217295

Comment: Club member is not an id but a boolean variable denoting if the user is a club member. Each row is a user. Poor naming on my part, sorry

Comment: https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/group_split.html -- this may be what you're looking for.

Comment: No Worries, that helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this out

```
library(tidyverse)
mydf %>%
   rownames_to_column("ID") %>%
   mutate(map_of_blah = str_remove_all(map_of_blah, "\\{|\\}") %>% 
          str_split(., ",\\s")) %>% 
   unnest() %>%
   separate(col = map_of_blah, into = c("newcol", "newval"), sep = "=") %>%
   mutate(newcol = str_trim(newcol, "both"),
          newval = as.numeric(newval)) %>%
   spread(newcol, newval)
```

We first make an ID for the user, then we separate all the items in the map of blah, then we unnest to long format. After, we separate the column so that we get two new colums (one of the headers and one of values). Lastly, we spread to wide.

Let me know if anything is unclear.

Comment: Just as a follow up. My actual data are close to 5M rows and I keep running out of memory. Any ideas on to make this more efficient in that regard?

Comment: I'm sure there are ways to speed up the regex part. Other than that, I don't think I have any ideas right away.

Answer (score 3):

Here is one option with `str_extract` and `spread`.  Using `str_extract_all`, get the concerned substring from  the 'map_of_blah' as a `list` column, `unnest` the dataset, change the type (`type_convert` from `readr`), and `spread` to 'wide' format

```
library(tidyverse)
mydf %>% 
  transmute(ID = row_number(), club_member, 
            key = str_extract_all(map_of_blah, "\\w+(?=\\=)"), 
            val = str_extract_all(map_of_blah, "(?<=\\=)[0-9.]+")) %>% 
  unnest(c(key, val)) %>%
  type_convert %>% 
  spread(key, val) %>%
  select(-"<NA>")
# A tibble: 6 x 8
#     ID club_member Apples   Boost Improve MystBox  Upgrade WalkoffGm
#  <int>       <int>  <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl>
#1     1           0 NA     NA       NA      NA     NA         NA     
#2     2           0 NA     NA       NA      NA      1         NA     
#3     3           1  0.328  0.0656   0.525  NA     NA          0.0820
#4     4           0 NA     NA       NA      NA     NA         NA     
#5     5           0 NA     NA       NA       0.998  0.00222   NA     
#6     6           0 NA     NA       NA      NA     NA         NA
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way with `dplyr` and `tidyr` -

```
mydf %>% 
  mutate(
    user_id = 1:n(), # create id for each row
    map_of_blah = gsub("\\{|\\}", "", map_of_blah) # remove {,}
  ) %>% 
  separate_rows(map_of_blah, sep = ",") %>% # separate attributes into rows
  # separate attributes into columns
  separate(map_of_blah, into = c("var", "value"), sep = "=", convert = T) %>%
  mutate(var = trimws(var)) %>% # remove white spaces at the ends
  spread(var, value) %>% 
  select(user_id, club_member, Apples:WalkoffGm)

  user_id club_member    Apples   Improve In-Game Boost   MystBox     Upgrade  WalkoffGm
1       1           0        NA        NA            NA        NA          NA         NA
2       2           0        NA        NA            NA        NA 1.000000000         NA
3       4           0        NA        NA            NA        NA          NA         NA
4       5           0 1.0000000        NA            NA 0.9977827 0.002217295         NA
5       6           0        NA        NA            NA        NA          NA         NA
6       3           1 0.3278689 0.5245902    0.06557377        NA          NA 0.08196721
```